# How to detect pulse duration with CMOS circuit

Tags: cmos, pulse

I have created a circuit where I want to detect a pulse width, but unfortunately I can't get what I want. I think my circuit is totally wrong. I am looking online to find a solution, but the closest solution which I found was the Duty Cycle Adjusting Circuit for Clock Signals, which is not what I need.

I need a circuit that will output a voltage proportional to the pulse width of the input voltage.
I want to get this output.
[image]

[image]

But all I get is triangle wave generator.

So I have changed the circuit a little bit and I have got a result closer to the desired output. With the proposed solutions is a little bit hard to understand what I should do to achieve my desired output.

[image]

Here is the output that I get:

[image]

I want v(net2) to start from 0 and be more linear after the pulse. I have also designed another circuit but there I get something completely wrong.

Here is alternative circuit:

[image]

And the output of this circuit is:

[image]

Which is not even closer to the first solution.
Help me to achieve the desired solution given in the first picture.

Comment: Is C1 supposed to be 0.1F? Try changing it to 0.1uF.

Comment: No. I just decided to make it smaller and see what happens. I was using 0.1pF.

Comment: It's call a Tachometer circuit. ( a one shot at any f[Hz] up to 1/T [s] with a LPF )

Comment: PWM at a given f has a spectrum that if filtered causes latency on BW of the "signal" so this will have ripple according to filter rejection, otherwise use a digital TI counter DAC and higher LPF for less latency. This "problem" lacks specs on signal BW , PWM rate and ripple & latency spec. !! Not just a failure to make an average voltage.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thank you very much for the comment. I need to do some research to understand your solution. Unfortunately, I don't have enough background.

Comment: The analog method uses integrate then S&H then dump integrator and repeat on rising edge with small LPF on S&H output using analog switch.  As I said define your Signal BW, PWM rate, ripple spec and delay spec (LPF latency, RC=T)

Answer (score 2):

All you'd do is charge a capacitor (C1) with the current pulse. I don't know why you'd need M3 and M4 for that, seeing that neither "adds" any external current sourcing, and I don't see why you'd need M5 or anything connected to that.

The full circuit you need is a single capacitor connected between ground and your pulse source.

Comment: Thank you! I have got something closer to my desired output. But the voltage at net6 is increasing and decreasing when the pulse is starting. I want it to go linear when the pulse is starting ,that way I will have a pulse-width detection.

Comment: Use a one shot and LPF to reduce the ripple.

Comment: then you have something that doesn't behave like the perfect pulse source you're showing, and/or something that doesn't behave like a perfect capacitor.

Comment: The very definition of capacitor is that the voltage over it is the integral of current over time. So maybe your pulse source is not a current source? In that case, make a voltage-controlled current source and attach that to the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Simple PWM to DC voltage converter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6K12r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

---

### Fast PWM to DC converter, T2>= 2 x T1

**Bandwidth of DC + AC signal = 0.35/T2**  for T2 rise time= 10 to 90% PWM Vmax

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFQ8gS.png)</sup>

Although this is extreme PWM modulation example, PWM goes from 25%,50%,75%,100%,25% to illustrate PWM to DC method conversion.

It  works for any 0 to 100% with PWM using edge detection, , needing Vref for  cap current, with edge detector on rising edge to S&H fast then dump integrator fast , then integrate slow and repeat just using analog switches and small plastic caps or COG caps or non-memory caps.

You just need to know how to get pulse from dV/dt and integrate with extreme high and low resistance during pulse off,On time for fast attack and slow decay.

### Other

Otherwise like any Tachometer that converts RPM to Vdc, using 1 shot average voltage circuit with no integration just a LPF. But RPM rate of change is slow unless RPM rate is very high.

Same holds true for PWM frequency and signal DC-bandwidth causing delay and ripple.  Fourier spectrum instantly tells you specs you need for LPF breakpoint and slope you would need given a ripple and delay spec. (but I digress)

Comment: I am currently trying to understand your answer , but honestly I am not able to , because I don't posses enough background.. Can I make my desired output just using the nmos/pmos without making S & H. Isn't this solution making this circuit more complicating ?

Comment: Maybe It depends on the specs I defined which you need to understand. I define two ways, simple with just an RC LPF and lots of delay or fast with S&H. No other analog way.